# 99% CPU, 3.51MB without typedef

Tags: c++, c++11

Ok so I have roughly 500 function pointers defined in a header like so for example:

```
void (__stdcall *ptr_glAccum) (GLenum op, GLfloat value);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glActiveTextureARB) (GLenum texture);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glAlphaFunc) (GLenum func, GLclampf ref);
GLboolean (__stdcall *ptr_glAreTexturesResident) (GLsizei n, const GLuint *textures, GLboolean *residences);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glArrayElement) (GLint index);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glBegin) (GLenum mode);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glBindBufferARB) (GLenum target, GLuint buffer);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glBindTexture) (GLenum target, GLuint texture);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glBitmap) (GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLfloat xorig, GLfloat yorig, GLfloat xmove, GLfloat ymove, const GLubyte *bitmap);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glBlendFunc) (GLenum sfactor, GLenum dfactor);
void (__stdcall *ptr_glBufferDataARB) (GLenum target, GLsizeiptrARB size, const GLvoid *data, GLenum usage);
```

Etc.. Now the reason I did not put the typedef or did not want to was because I can assign to and use the pointers above directly. However, if I use the typedef, then I need to create a variable of said type and assign to it then use it. That just doubles my code from 500 lines to 1000+.

Now when I add a typedef at the beginning of each of those function pointers, my dll is 300kb and compiles in less than 5 seconds.. However, if I remove the typedef as show above, it skyrockets to 99% cpu when compiling and outputs a 3.51MB dll all while taking 3-4 minutes to compile.. Its outrageous that one keyword causes so much trouble.

Within the DLL's def file, it shows:

```
ptr_wglUseFontBitmapsA @940 DATA
ptr_wglUseFontBitmapsW @941 DATA
ptr_wglUseFontOutlinesA @942 DATA
ptr_wglUseFontOutlinesW @943 DATA
```

But with the typedef, that "DATA" part is gone.

Any ideas what makes the typedef so special and why this behaviour without it :S? I'm using Mingw G++ 4.7.2 with Codeblocks Windows-7 x64 3.7Ghz I7 8Gb Ram with the compiler output being:

```
-------------- Clean: Release in OpenGL32 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "OpenGL32 - Release"

-------------- Build: Release in OpenGL32 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -O2  -std=c++11 -Wall -DBUILD_DLL  -std=c++11    -c C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\OpenGL32\Implementations\Exports.cpp -o obj\Release\Implementations\Exports.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -O2  -std=c++11 -Wall -DBUILD_DLL  -std=c++11    -c C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\OpenGL32\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Release\libOpenGL32.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libOpenGL32.a -Wl,--dll  obj\Release\Implementations\Exports.o obj\Release\main.o   -o bin\Release\OpenGL32.dll -s -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++  -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 
Output size is 3.51 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (2 minutes, 39 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (2 minutes, 39 seconds)
```

**EDIT: Entire DLL (containing only 1/500 func pointers as requested):**

Exports.hpp:

```
#ifndef EXPORTS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define EXPORTS_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include "Platform.hpp"


extern Library* OriginalGL;

void (__stdcall *ptr_glAccum) (GLenum op, GLfloat value);

#endif // EXPORTS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Exports.cpp:

```
#include "Exports.hpp"

Library* OriginalGL = nullptr;

bool __stdcall Initialized(void)
{
    char Root[MAX_PATH];
    #if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
        GetSystemDirectoryA(Root, MAX_PATH);
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        strcat_s(Root, "\\opengl32.dll");
    #else
        strcat(Root, "\\opengl32.dll");
    #endif
    #else
        strcat(Root, "/usr/lib");
        strcat(Root, "/libGL.so");
    #endif

    OriginalGL = new Library(Root);
    return  OriginalGL->FunctionAddress(ptr_glAccum, "glAccum"); //Just a thin class wrapper around GetProcAddress and LoadLibrary.
}

bool __stdcall DeInitialize(void)
{
    if (OriginalGL)
    {
        delete OriginalGL;
        OriginalGL = nullptr;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

extern "C" __stdcall void DetourHook_glAccum(GLenum op, GLfloat value)
{
    (*ptr_glAccum) (op, value);
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" bool __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this specific to a particular compiler?  Specifying the compiler you are using, as well as its version, may be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "add  a typedef at the beginning"? Can you please show some example of that too?

Comment: I'm using Mingw's g++ with Codeblocks IDE on Windows x64 3.7Ghz I7 8GB ram. :S I mean like this: `typedef void (__stdcall *ptr_glAccum) (GLenum op, GLfloat value);`

Comment: If you define the variables as shown, you should not see any difference in DLL sizes with or without the typedef. If you do see the difference then you are doing something wrong. We don't know what, as you are not explaining everything you are doing and not showing the entire code. Trim your DLL to a single function, verify that it compiles, and without any further editing or trimming post the code verbatim in its entirety.

Comment: Updated OP as requested.

Comment: I named it in the comments above but I guess I'll put it in OP now that you mentioned it.

Comment: You need the compiler version string.  And compile command-line.  Doesn't matter that you're using Code::Blocks.  Windows version shouldn't be important, but surely would be more so than the speed of your processor.

Comment: Ok I updated the OP with my command line arguments the Codeblocks prints.

Comment: Thanks.  And those are the same (e.g. `-static`) for both attempts?

Comment: I don't understand why you're constructing an explicit path to `LoadLibrary`, but that shouldn't have any affect on the size of your DLL.  If the output of `dumpbin`/`nm` significantly different when used on DLLs built either way?

Comment: Explicit path? @ your previous question: All the options are the same. The only thing that makes it behave like this is the typedef keyword. Just incase you want the whole project: http://pastebin.com/khhSN4Mb, http://pastebin.com/CSR3pYyi, http://pastebin.com/1NXH6wCn

Again.. only when I DONT use typedef, it skyrockets and lags and outputs large. If I use typedef and create 500 variables of said type, the DLL works fine and compiles in a second or two.

Comment: Where is the typedef version?

Comment: Exports.hpp(typedef version): http://pastebin.com/D7ARk2aN and Exports.cpp(typedef version): http://pastebin.com/jNcfkB3M
Platforms.hpp/.cpp is still the same and they both still GetFunctionAddress the same. Notice that Exports.hpp/.cpp typedef is 2-3x the size of the non-typedef due to me having to create 500+ variables.

Comment: You have changed your variable names. In the no-typedef version you have a variable named `ptr_glAccum`, in the typedef version the variable is named `optr_glAccum`. If you have a .def file that lists  `ptr_glAccum` and not `optr_glAccum`, then that's your difference right here.

Comment: But why? The optr_glAccum is the exact same type as ptr_glAccum. The compiler generates the .def files. Only difference between optr and ptr is it is an alias through the typedef keyword. I can't use the typedef directly so a variable with a different name had to be created. Both are the same function pointer and type :S

Comment: Have you looked at the .def file? What does it say?

Comment: Both are the same.. Same number of exports, same ordinals, same names, everything. I even tried writing my own.. I give up on this. I'm just going to use the typedef version because there just has to be something special about that keyword for this case.

Comment: That's your problem. The def files are the same but the obj files are different. The def file should match the obj file. Rename your X typedefs to X_t and your oX variables to X.

Comment: Please show the typedef and non-typedef versions of your code *in the question*. Comments and pastebin links are ephemeral, and may not be available for future readers.

Comment: Why not declare the functions using the typedef in the first place? There is no need for 500 function pointers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `typedef` your header is producing a lot of new types, each being a function pointer type. Types are useful for compilation process only and produce no trace in the DLL itself. `typedef` does *not* produce any global variables.

However, without `typedef` your header is producing a series of global variables, each being a function pointer. Global variables do take an entry in the DLL, increasing the file production time and its final size.

Comment: Yes but I still have to create those global variables using the typedef so what difference does that make :S See the Updated OP sample with typedef?

Comment: I guess I'll accept your answer unless someone else has a better idea but I still see no difference between using the typedef and declaring a bunch of globals vs. using the function pointer directly. Wiki doesn't say anything other than typedef being an alias.

Comment: Added a line to my answer. `typedef` does *not* produce global variables! Most likely you want global variables here, not types.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: It's not that you used `typedef`; it's that you took the resulting type aliases and created 500 function pointers with them. You didn't need to do that.

Comment: How else do you use aliases since you can't use the typedef directly :S

Comment: It's a *type alias* (hence *type*def). You use it as types, not values. You could have for example: `typedef void (__stdcall *ptr_glAccumType) (GLenum op, GLfloat value); ptr_glAccumType ptr_glAccum;`